# How to implement EOF in Antlr4 Grammar

Tags: t-sql, antlr4, grammar

I have a grammar that I am using for TSQL-esque language validation. Currently the grammar rules will work with a statement such as `SUM(column1) + SUM(column2)`.

I would like the parser to throw an error if it was given something like
`SUM(column1) SUM(column2)`. Notice the lack of an operator between the two SUMs. Right now, if I run this statement through the parser it does not error out. Instead it will return the first part of the statement, `SUM(column1)` and completely disregard the rest of the statement.

Upon research, I believe the answer to my problem is adding a EOF to my grammar. I have tried to implement this in several ways but it has not made any difference to the parsing.

This is the best way I can think to implement it in my grammar file, in the argument_list:

```
grammar DataAnalysis;

expression          : literal                                   #literalAtomExp
                    | FUNCTION=ID '(' argument_list ')'         #functionExp
                    | INLINE_FUNCTION '(' argument_list ')'     #inlineFunctionExp
                    | '(' expression ')'                        #parenthesisExp
                    | expression (ASTERISK|SLASH) expression    #mulDivExp
                    | expression (PLUS|MINUS) expression        #addSubExp
                    | <assoc=right>  expression '^' expression  #powerExp
                    | QUOTEDTEXT                                #stringExp
                    ;


argument_list       : expression (',' expression)* EOF //implemented here
                    ;


literal             : (TABLE_NAME=ID '.')? COLUMN_NAME=ID
                    | VALUE=NUMBER
                    ;

fragment NAME       : [a-zA-Z0-9_]  ;
fragment LETTER     : [a-zA-Z]      ;
fragment DIGIT      : [0-9]         ;

ASTERISK            : '*' ;
SLASH               : '/' ;
PLUS                : '+' ;
MINUS               : '-' ;

INLINE_FUNCTION     : 'YEAR'
                    | 'MONTH'
                    | 'DAY'
                    ;

NUMBER              : ('-')? DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)? ;

ID                  : LETTER (NAME+) ;

QUOTEDTEXT          : '"' .*? '"' ;

WHITESPACE          : ' ' -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Even like this the parsing doesn't pick up on the issue and returns only the first part of the query.

To summarize, when I feed the parser `SUM(column1) SUM(column2)` I would like it to return an error because it doesn't have any associated rule for that case.

Don't know what I am missing. Thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Augment the grammar with "expr_prime : expression EOF;", and remove the EOF from the argument_list rule. Start parsing with expr_prime().

Comment: I ended up just calling it "parse" instead of "expr_prime". I believe the underscore was giving me some issues.